# How to Locate a Dynamically Changing Element in Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on an element that stays roughly the same but changes a bit with each page refresh. For example, sometimes the CSS value will be `#pmts-id-49-announce` sometimes it will be `#pmts-id-44-announce` and sometimes another number. The issue is I cannot know in advance what number it will be (it could be anything).

I understand to resolve this specific issue I could use @contains method in XPath but the real issue is there is another element which changes in the same way and it would be impossible to know which is which. In other words, sometimes the element I'm looking for will be 44 but sometimes the other element will be the one which is 44 - it's impossible to know beforehand which element will get which number.

How can I locate such an element in this circumstance?

I'm using Java, Selenium, XPath/CSS.

Thanks

Comment: can you share some more html code? maybe you can find a unique selector with multiple element

Comment: is there anything else than the ID that defines the element you want? some text content maybe?